# Display a number from array in PHP

Tags: php

Hello I would like to have a code that displays randomly from an array a number and displays it.
For example this code

```
<?php
$firstquarter = array(1 => 'January', 'February', 'March');
print_r($firstquarter);
?>
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [1] => January
    [2] => February
    [3] => March
)
```

Instead of this, I would like to display on

Comment: Are you searching for something like [`array_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)? Your questions isn't *that* clear...

Comment: Again you're questing isn't very clear. Please clarify.

Comment: Noy your question is very unclear, what's defines the difference from 15:00 and 18:00 ?

Comment: What are the intervals for the server time?

Comment: Actually, I'm not changing my answer now, you should be creating a new post for this, its bad practise to totally change the whole question.

Comment: Rolled the revision back - you shouldn't change the question completely (as @RobertPitt mentioned).  Start a new one.

Answer (score 3):

A simple function called `array_rand`

example:

```
$selection = array_rand($my_array);
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

Answer (score 2):

Use rand()

```
$iIndex = rand(1, count($firstquarter));
echo $firstquarter[$iIndex];
```

This assumes you have an one indexed array with consecutive keys.

Comment: Oh great for this. I found this code <?php
echo rand(5, 15);
?> However I want a different range depends on time. For example if the server time is 15:00 to 18:00 it will have a different range than 18:01 to 21:00 and so on. UPDATED ENTIRE QUESTION

Comment: @RobertPitt Ha. never come across that function. Submit your own answer and I'll give you an up vote.

Comment: Hehe, by "so on" I mean you know 21:01 to 24:01... I need an example to know how it is working

Answer (score 2):

You need `array_rand()`:

```
echo $firstquarter[array_rand($firstquarter)];
```

---

I'm not sure if this is what you want but here it goes:

```
echo mt_rand(intval(date('H') / 3) * 4, intval(date('H') / 3) * 5);
```

Comment: The question has been rolled back as the OP changed the whole context of the question, +1 for posting anyway.

Comment: @RobertPitt: Yup, I see. I got somewhat confused with the rollback there.